# reading files from path with wildcard does not work - Databricks JSON

Tags: python, json, databricks

trying to read a JSON file from databricks with the following code

```
  with open('/dbfs/mnt/bronze/categories/20221006/data_10.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

which works perfecyl but problem is that I would like to use the wild cards since there are multiple folders and files. Preferebly want to make the below code working

```
with open('/dbfs/mnt/bronze/categories/**/*.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

when I read JSON using spark, wildcards work perfectly. But I prefer the above option

```
df = spark.read.json(f'/mnt/bronze/AKENEO/categories/**/*.json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a quick script that goes through the folders using `os.walk`.
You can see an example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)

Basically it will allow you not to use the wildcards at all, but will require some more code.